# Accessing data associated with the RepeaterItem on Command execution

Tags: asp.net, events, repeater

I want to access the data associated with the RepeaterItem in which an ItemCommand fired up. The scenario is, I have multiple RepeaterItems which Button controls in which the Command is set declaratively like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater3" 
              runat="server" 
              DataSource='<%# ClientManager.GetClientEmployees(Eval("ClientID")) %>' 
              OnItemCommand="RemoveEmployeeFromClient">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Text="(x)" 
                        CommandName="RemoveEmployeeFromClient">
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>

    <SeparatorTemplate>,<br /></SeparatorTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The code behind is:

```
Protected Sub RemoveEmployeeFromClient(ByVal source As Object, 
                                       ByVal e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    ' I want to access the data associated with 
    ' the RepeaterItem which the Button was clicked.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use e.Item.DataItem to get down to the data for the object, or you could store it in a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Mitchel said, make sure you check to see that the RowType is [DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx).  Don't want to do crap when you can't.  The cast from e.Item.DataItem to your type would fail on the header or footer row.